# Ternary Operator in C (including Objective-C & C++) - Do Nothing on Else Condition

Tags: objective-c, c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Just wanted to get some clarification from you guys. I'm trying to figure out how to do nothing on the else condition of an instruction that uses a ternary operator in Objective-C. I started doing something like the following which seems to work perfectly fine but I'm just hoping there's no weird voodoo going on in the background.

```
(condition) ? [object method] : nil; 
self.intNumber = (localIntNumber) ? localIntNumber : self.intNumber; // set intNumber to itself if localIntNumber doesn't exist
self.myObject = (newObject) ? newObject : self.myObject; // different from intNumber in that we're dealing with a Foundation object (can be nil) instead of a regular int
```

Any of the above kosher to do? Thoughts?

Comment: `self.intNumber = (localIntNumber) ? localIntNumber : self.intNumber;` is totally appropriate, assuming that `self.intNumber` is already a valid value.

Comment: You can even do `self.intNumber = localIntNumber ?: self.intNumber;`

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! What about for the new scenario I just put in dealing with a Foundation object?

Comment: @Cornelius `self.intNumber = localIntNumber ?: self.intNumber;` is an c extension that allows omitting the second operand and is equivalent to `self.intNumber = localIntNumber ? localIntNumber : self.intNumber`;

Comment: They might work, but they are difficult to read and all could be replaced with more efficient and easier-to-read `if` statements.

Comment: @david.pfx Technically speaking the ternary operator came from C and Objective-C is a superset of C (and so is C++). I put the question down for Objective-C, but whatever is discussed here will work within any of the aforementioned languages

Comment: @trojanfoe That efficiency you speak of is really dependent on how the compiler interprets the instructions. And I'd actually argue that the ternary operator is cleaner and more concise than its `if/else` equivalent in some cases

Comment: In some cases, yes, however the examples you give all favour the use of an `if` statement (with no `else`).  So it looks like for things that need a "do nothing else condition" avoiding the ternary operator is best.

Comment: @DanielSanchez: No, the ternary conditional operator is slightly different in C and C++ (and C++ isn't a superset of C, but Objective-C is).

Comment: What @trojanfoe said.  Readability trumps almost all other arguments.

Comment: @Hyperbole You're saying an instruction using a ternary operator isn't readable? I think it's more succinct and readable than an `if/else` when used correctly -- but that's just my personal opinion

Comment: @DanielSanchez No, I made a logical leap in my head.  Check out my answer for my reasoning.

Comment: @DanielSanchez: `[object method]` and `self` and `localIntNumber` and `?:` are not found in the C I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these are acceptable, read the same way and are compiled the same way:

`self.intNumber = (localIntNumber) ? localIntNumber : self.intNumber;`
`self.myObject = (newObject) ? newObject : self.myObject;`

This is also acceptable, as indicated by @Cornelius:

`self.intNumber = localIntNumber ?: self.intNumber;` 
`self.myObject = newObject ?: self.myObject;`

This way of using the ternary operator isn't very common, though.  Remember, you're writing code for your future self (and maybe others), so anything unnecessarily cryptic should be avoided.

### Code readability should be high on your list of considerations when writing code

Thanks @trojanfoe for bringing this up.

If you're not having an `else` condition, **I'd strongly recommend one of these**:

```
if (localIntNumber) {
    self.intNumber = localIntNumber
}

if (newObject) {
    self.myObject = newObject;
}
```

Assuming, of course, that you've already set `self.intNumber` and `self.myObject` to valid values previously as to obviate the need for the `else` condition.

Comment: +1 There is also a small performance gain with the `if` statement as the "else" side of the ternary operator is re-assigning the value with itself in some of the examples given in the question. However it's entirely possible the compiler is smart enough to see the futility in this and optimize it out.

Comment: Don't let my comments fool you. I've been enjoying this discussion we've been having. I appreciate you guys taking the time to outline your thoughts on the matter here :).

Comment: No foolery here, just an unexplained leap.  Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: I often write `if (localIntNumber) self.intNumber = localIntNumber;` all one line with no braces to remind myself this is a value-only operation and not intended to be a flow-of-control. I find this better than the one-sided ternary, although not by much.